# Android - Null pointer exception for this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext()

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, cordova-plugins, cordova-android

I have created plugin for android. Now inside the plugin I want to access application context.

I got below solution to get context of CordovaPlugin class

```
Context context = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext()
```

But while running it throws below error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.app.Activity org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface.getActivity()' on a null object reference
10-24 01:25:41.930 16692-16751/io.ionic.starter W/System.err:     at cordova.plugin.testpayment.TestPayment.<init>(TestPayment.java:25)
10-24 01:25:41.930 16692-16751/io.ionic.starter W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
10-24 01:25:41.930 16692-16751/io.ionic.starter W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.instantiatePlugin(PluginManager.java:492)
10-24 01:25:41.930 16692-16751/io.ionic.starter W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:169)
10-24 01:25:41.930 16692-16751/io.ionic.starter W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:122)
10-24 01:25:41.930 16692-16751/io.ionic.starter W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
10-24 01:25:41.931 16692-16751/io.ionic.starter W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemExposedJsApi.exec(SystemExposedJsApi.java:41)
10-24 01:25:41.931 16692-16751/io.ionic.starter W/System.err:     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
10-24 01:25:41.931 16692-16751/io.ionic.starter W/System.err:     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:9)
10-24 01:25:41.931 16692-16751/io.ionic.starter W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-24 01:25:41.931 16692-16751/io.ionic.starter W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
```

I can see error as `NullPointerException`.

May I know what's wrong in it?

Comment: `this.cordova` is null

Comment: What do I need to do to resolve it?

Comment: Can you share your plugin xml

Answer (score 1):

Please use this

```
Context context = IS_AT_LEAST_LOLLIPOP ? cordova.getActivity().getWindow().getContext() : cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```